# Javascript array element not set via function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I've been trying to figure this out for a long long time, and would appreciate any help.

The code is as follows, which can be seen here http://incoming.comule.com/isnan.html

```
<script>
var price = new Array();

function add(price) {
//alert("function add: is price not a number? = "+isNaN(price));
price[0] = price;
}

function addman() {
price[0] = 0.87;
}

function status() {
alert(price[0]);
}

function num() {
alert("function Number: is price not a number? = "+isNaN(Number(price[0])));
}

function pInt() {
alert("function parseInt: is price not a number? = "+isNaN(parseInt(price[0])));
}

function pFloat() {
alert("function parseFloat: is price not a number? = "+isNaN(parseFloat(price[0])));
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:add('0.45');">Add price 0.45</a> then click ... <a href="javascript:status();">status</a> ,
 <a href="javascript:num();">number</a> , <a href="javascript:pInt();">parseInt</a> , <a href="javascript:pFloat();">parseFloat</a>

<p>

<a href="javascript:addman();">set manually</a>
```

When I click add price, then status, it shows as undefined, but when I click set manually then status, the status shows the value. The only difference is how it is being set, does anyone know how I can add this via a function variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rename your `Array` to something other than `price`. Inside the `add` function `price` refers to the function parameter, not the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your array and function argument share the same name. The latter supercedes the former in the function scope, so you are effectively losing access to the outer array.

Change the argument name and you'll be fine.